# UITableview dynamic height as per subview dimensions

Tags: uiimageview

I am creating 3 views in one row of UITableview. Each view contains UIImageView. UIImageView url is coming from web services. I am able to get the height and width of image from url. I am just stuck on one part i am getting different height or every image then how will i resize the superview to same height as per the highest height of one of the 3 images of single row.

```
For example:- i have created 1st view of a row 
1st image height is 50
1st image height is 80
1st image height is 100
```

I am able to get the highest height but how will i assign the dimension after already created UIView. Then, how will i resize again the 1st view(which is already created with height 50) and 2nd view(which is already created with height 80) with highest height(100) image of row

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my query. it's bit tricky but a difficult functionality

Thanks